# Clojure multimethods global hierarchy

Tags: clojure

In the docs it says

> All of the examples above use the global hierarchy used by the multimethod system

What is the global hierarchy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj) and look for `(def ^{:private true} global-hierarchy (make-hierarchy))`. The doc string for `make-hierarchy` says

> "Creates a hierarchy object for use with derive, isa? etc."

The relationship of this with multimethod system can be find out by doing a `macroexpand` on `defmulti` which results in a call to `clojure.lang.MultiFn` constructor with the method name as string and also the var `#'clojure.core/global-hierarchy`. You can look into `clojure.lang.MultiFn` source if you want but that is "under the hood" of multimethods.